# Xamarin Binding error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method build()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a [Binding Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar) for [Triton Digital Mobile SDK](https://userguides.tritondigital.com/spc/moband/index.html) and integrated it on my Xamarin.Android project.

I have added this code to my project to test the binding library

```
using Com.Tritondigital.Player;
namespace MyProject.Droid.Services
{
    public class AudioSource : Service, AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener
    {
        .
        .
        .
        public void Play()
        {
            Bundle settings = new Bundle();
            settings.PutString(TritonPlayer.SettingsStreamUrl, "http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3");

            // Create the player.
            TritonPlayer player = new TritonPlayer(this, settings);
            player.Play();
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But during runtime, it throws a FATAL EXCEPTION

```
[TdStreamPlayer] SETTINGS_STREAM_MIME_TYPE not set. Deduced from URL: audio/mpeg
[TdStreamPlayer] SETTINGS_TRANSPORT not set. Deduced from URL: sc
[TdTritonPlayer] State changed: Stopped -> Connecting
[TdExoPlayerBkg] ExoPlayer URL: http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3
[TdExoPlayerBkg] ExoPlayer buffer start: 2500 rebuffer: 8000 timeout: 15000
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: com.company.myapp, PID: 8630
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method build()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl; in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl$Builder' appears in /data/app/com.company.myapp-bJibtmPeizHK0sfcwRqrpA==/base.apk)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.tritondigital.player.TdExoPlayer$PlayerHandler.b(SourceFile:97)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.tritondigital.player.TdExoPlayer$PlayerHandler.handleMessage(SourceFile:66)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: No virtual method build()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl; in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl$Builder' appears in /data/app/com.company.myapp-bJibtmPeizHK0sfcwRqrpA==/base.apk)
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method build()Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl; in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl$Builder' appears in /data/app/com.company.myapp-bJibtmPeizHK0sfcwRqrpA==/base.apk)
[MonoDroid]     at com.tritondigital.player.TdExoPlayer$PlayerHandler.b(SourceFile:97)
[MonoDroid]     at com.tritondigital.player.TdExoPlayer$PlayerHandler.handleMessage(SourceFile:66)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jar for exoplayer in your binding project with embeddedjar build action mentioned in the [documentation](https://userguides.tritondigital.com/spc/moband/android_sdk.html)

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer. Avoid pointing out some links without further explanations, your answer can be a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I can't add a comment to the question. When I click Add a comment it says "You must have 50 reputation to comment". As for the answer, I'll update it once I'm done with android binding. Right now I encountered another issue when consuming the binding after resolving that error.